# Cómo hago para que al copiar el código y que no me quede en una sola línea sino indentado (sangrado)

Tags: sql-server

Soy nueva con el SQL Management Studio 2019 y tengo un problema con el copiado y el pegado, tengo un procedimiento que me arroja una consulta estructurada y tabulada, al copiar el resultado del procedimiento y pegar el código en SQL este pierde el formato y me toca, manualmente, darle otra vez formato para poder leer la consulta.

Ejemplo.
El procedimiento arroja la consulta así:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tabla
WHERE Filtro > Condicion
```

Pero al copiarla y pegarla en el SQL queda así:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla WHERE Filtro > Condicion
```

Como la consulta es muy larga, tengo que volver a insertar los saltos
de línea para poder trabajar con ella cómodamente. Quisiera saber si existe alguna técnica para formatear adecuadamente la consulta.

---

Así que la pregunta es: cómo soluciono el problema para que al copiar el código no me quede en una sola línea sino indentado.
Buscando en la documentación de Microsoft hallamos la solución, solo es aplicar la siguiente configuración en el management.
Ingresar a Tools - Options - Query Results - expandir la opcion SQL Server - Results to Grid - Check en la opcion: Retain CR/LF on copy or save.

Comment: Y la pregunta es....?

Comment: Tal vez [este link](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-format-sql-code-in-sql-server-management-studio/) te ayude un poco

Comment: que procedimiento? donde la copias? donde la pegas? como esta, la pregunta no se entiende....

Comment: es un procedimiento almacenado que entrega como resultado una consulta SQL?. El resultado está en una fila?, es un `PRINT`?. Por favor, aclara tu pregunta

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.